# Cant block wordpress readme files

Tags: htaccess

Please review this .htaccess rules. I want to block all readme and such files and I am unable to do it.

```
Redirect 404 /install.php
Redirect 404 readme.html

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule (?:readme|license|changelog|-config|-sample)\.(?:php|md|txt|html?) - [R=404,NC,L]
RewriteRule \.(?:psd|log|cmd|exe|bat|c?sh)$ - [NC,F]


</IfModule>
Options All -Indexes

<files wp-config.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>

<files ~ "^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])">
order allow,deny
deny from all
satisfy all
</files>


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need these:

```
Redirect 404 /install.php
Redirect 404 readme.html
```

To block `readme.html` you do this:

```
<files readme.html>
         order allow,deny
         deny from all
</files>
```

For other kind of files you need do the same just change file name in code.