# How to block access to files without modifying .htaccess or ngnix config?

Tags: htaccess, wp-config, filesystem, user-access, readme

I'm trying to prevent access to readme.txt files on a WP site. Normally, this would be easy by just [modifying the .htaccess file](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/268730/134617) or the [ngnix configuration](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/nginx-block-url-access-all-except-one-ip-address/).

However, the host runs [ngnix, which ignores .htaccess files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29678631/htaccess-not-working-on-drupal-7-when-uploaded-to-pantheon-server#29679352), and the host [doesn't allow changes to ngnix configuration](https://pantheon.io/docs/redirects/).

This seems to leave PHP as the only way to block access. But this doesn't seem to work either. I have the following as the first lines of wp-config.php:

```
<?php
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "readme.txt") !== false){
    header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 404 Not Found", true, 404);
    include("404.shtml");
    exit;
}
```

When I go to an url of a readme.txt file that exists on the server, I still see the contents of the file and not the 404 I'm expecting.

I believe this happens because ngnix checks for the file's existence, finds it, and then directly serves it, bypassing PHP/WP.

Another, host-specific option is to block files using the [a .yml file](https://pantheon.io/docs/pantheon-yml/). However, that particular method does not allow wildcards, is only limited to 25 file names and would need to be updated whenever a new readme.txt file is added.

**Is there any way to block access to all readme.txt files on a WP site without modifying .htaccess or ngnix configuration?**

Comment: You won't be able to block access to files without hosting intervention, or htaccess/nginx changes, the only way you're going to get an answer is by asking Pantheon support. Keep in mind that 3rd party services ( e.g. hosts ) are not on topic here

Comment: @TomJNowell Understood. I was hoping to write my question in such a way that it would be applicable to any other host that has similar restrictions as Pantheon. Let me know if you feel it sounds too specific to Pantheon and I'll rephrase it.

Comment: That's not possible, this will always require the host to intervene, or HTAccess/Nginx modifications. The only other alternative I can think of is to go into each plugin and manually delete the readme files. Note that this will not improve security, and if that's the reasoning behind it then it won't work. Attackers don't check the plugin version before attacking, they just launch the attack anyway, WP sites will get attacks for ancient versions of WP, and even Drupal attacks, it's easier to fire and forget than to analyse a site and tailor the attack

Comment: Other than that, the answer is **no** you need Apache/Nginx access, or to talk to your host

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the tip. Yes this is for security reasons. An automated scan from another part of our IT department complains about the readme files and I was looking for a way to block them to appease the scanner. I'll talk to Pantheon support.